# AKS Standard Load Balancer TCP Reset Annotations

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

We are upgrading our AKS cluster in order to use Standard SKU load balancers that went GA recently. See this [Microsoft Update Notification](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/standard-load-balancers-in-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/).Previously only basic SKU load balancers were available and they  would not allow us to send a TCP reset when connections went stale. This lead to a lot of creative work arounds to deal with stale connections in connection pools for example.

So during creation of an ingress I can configur the load balancer by using annontations. For example I can set type to  internal and timeout settings using annotations. However being able to set the TCP reset flag to true via annotations does not seem possible. I have found with some digging a list of the annotations in this [Go Walker](https://gowalker.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/azure) page.

I have managed to create a ingress controller using the following yaml. *Note the annonations.*

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: 172.15.23.100
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout: "15"
```

I ran the following commands:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress -f dev-ingress.yaml --name dev-ingress --set controller.replicaCount=3
```

After a minute or so I can see the internal loadbalancer getting the specified IP address and I can also see it on the console see below:

```
kubectl -n ingress get svc dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller         LoadBalancer   172.15.24.11   172.15.23.100   80:30962/TCP,443:30364/TCP   24m   app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=dev-ingress
```

However the load balancing rules are created with a TCP reset to false. Which requires me to log into the console and change it. See screen shot below:

[image: DefaultTCPRule]

I really would like to script this into the creation as doing things via interfaces leads to Snowflake deployments.

Something like the yaml below:

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: 172.15.23.100
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout: "15"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-reset: "true"
```

Anyone know how I can configure this during service/ingress creation?

**Update:**

Based on the limitations documented on the [TCP Reset setting for loadbalancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-reset) document it appears that it is not supported from kubectl. However it also says that the portal is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Cloud provider for Azure](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cloud-provider-azure/blob/master/docs/services/README.md). It provides an annotation to set the TCP reset of the load balancer rules, but it's only available for version 1.16 or later and the latest version for AKS is 1.15.

[image]

You can use aks-engine to achieve your purpose if you really want to use it. The aks-engine already supports version 1.16 for Kubernetes. Remember, create the aks-engine cluster with the standard load balancer.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will keep an eye out for this release so I can work it into my yaml files.

Answer (score 2):

seeing [this file](https://gowalker.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/azure) does not have such an annotation I would conclude this is not yet possible with annotations. you'd have to figure some other way, or create a pull request to kubernetes to support such an annotation

Comment: I suspect as much. Will keep the question open for a day or two then if there is no answers create a pull request.